# Can I use both pip and easy_install or do the conflict?

Tags: python, easy-install, pip

I am currently using easy_install, but have been advised to use pip.

Can I start using pip or will things conflict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no problem at all. The same happened to me and I have no regrets. Pip is indeed much better. I would also recommend virtualenv. Here's a tutorial: http://iamzed.com/2009/05/07/a-primer-on-virtualenv/